# Can I add multi-mode fiber optic media converter at any point of my network previously distributed in single-mode fiber optic?

Tags: networking, optical-drive, optical-cable

I have used single-mode fiber optic media converter in my whole network. But my Fiber Optic cables have 2-pair of optical wires. I only use one of them for single-mode purpose. Now I want to introduce multi-mode fiber optic media converter boxes in some points of my network by using rest of the fiber ports of the cable. Is it possible to do so ?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the rest of the fiber ports of the cable"??? If you have extra singlemode fiber, no, you cannot use it with multimode media converters. The media converter type must match the fiber type (the fiber is the media, on the fiber side of a media converter)